# Why DRDY do not go low to indicate that the conversion is readyt in ADS1258?

Tags: c++, msp430, adc, high-voltage

MCU: MSP430F5438A
ADC: ADS1258
COM: SPI

I want to measure a voltage on a channel coming from the ADC (ADS1258), I am in fixed_Mode channel and in AIN2 positive AIN3 negatif, enabling status byte and i could configure all the registers of the ADC as I want but when I lunch the pulse convert command or an impulse on the START pin of the ADC to begin a convertion, i should wait till the DRDY pin will asserts low to indicate that the conversion is complete but this pin remains HIGH all the time.

I tried to make an impulse on START Pin and to send a pulse invert command

Comment: What does the status byte say, particularly the `NEW` bit?